# How can I find out the details of a check (who wrote it to me, etc.) that I already deposited into my bank account

Tags: india, banking, bank-account, check

I deposit a check into my Bank of India account which is from a account holder at Pujab National Bank. i forgot the details of check and the person who gave me that check. is there anyway to find out the check details or person's details??

Comment: The bank has this information. Can you please clarify why you can't ask them to provide it to you?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Perhaps he has forgotten the account number of his Bank of India account as well?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton If the check was clearing as physical paper, the Bank of India would not capture the details of Person. The cheque Number would be available.

Answer (score 1):

Online banking will allow you typically to view an image of the deposited check.

Otherwise, you can ask the bank for a copy.

Third, it might be printed on your monthly statement.

Comment: In India Online or Offline service does not provide this facility for image. Although India has implemented Check Truncation Service, it is not rolled out to all locations. Hence if the check followed the older process, the physical check would be sent to the drawn on bank via clearing.

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway to find out the check details or person's details??

Check Number generally will be available in you Bank Statement, or you net banking screen.

The Person who wrote the check, these details are not captured. Unless this check was deposited via CTS service, Bank of India will not have image or any other information on this check.